# How to conditionally tether my cellphone?

Tags: networking, tethering

I can do tethering with my cell phone.

Where I work, certain sites are blocked (gmail, yahoo mail, etc...).  Is there a way to tell windows to go through the cell phone on certain sites, but for all others, to go through the regular network card?

Comment: Who blocks gmail?

Comment: Interesting Handle.

Comment: @Josh, a lot of financial companies block webmail, forums, etc because they are required to keep records of all messages flowing in and out of the firm, which is not always easy to do with websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use a proxy, you may need to do this with the windows routing table.  By default the machine routes anything not on its local network to the internet through the preferred gateway.  You can set up rules that force certain interactions to go through the network adaptor and its associated gateway set up when you tether your phone.

It's not trivial, but it's possible.

Comment: yeah, that was my thought.  possible, not trivial.  ....oy.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that your workplace will be less than pleased with you if they find out that you're tethering your phone, effectively bypassing any protections that have in place.

That said, you can do this through your browser proxy settings. They differ slightly by browser, but effectively, you can point specific addresses, or ranges of address, or names, to a different proxy. Create a local proxy that points to your tethered phone, and set up your browser to use that proxy for the addresses or names you specify.

Comment: You'll also be creating a path to the internal network that's not protected by the corporate firewall/malware scanner.  Don't do it.

Comment: @Chris Nava.  Let's say I want to get my gmail at work and it is being blocked on the internal network.  I can already get it on my iPhone at work. So if the purpose of the block is to prevent me from receiving/sending out unauthorized emails, they've already failed.  Just the fact that I want to look at my email on a company issued computer vs a company issued iPhone, makes no difference at this point.

Comment: It's a TCP/IP connection not just an "email" connection.  Any network traffic can traverse it.